# How independent should fragments be from activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Fragments are introduced to create modularity.
Independent event handling and layout management seems reasonable.
What about stuff like networking, file io, ipc?

May a fragment have its own "back end" or must it delegate those responsibilities to the parent activity via Listener interface implemented by the latter?

Comment: Whether its a `Fragment` or an `Activity` consider that neither should have a back-end - rather they are de-coupled from any domain responsibilities - consider a MVP, MVC etc.. pattern. If an Activity or a Fragment is merely a view or UI then it makes life a lot easier as nothing is tightly coupled. BTW this question will probably just promote opinion based answers ... just like mine!

Comment: First of all it depends you really need Fragment or not, and then what your Fragment is doing, then many question arise like if only one Fragment needs to do network related task then why should it will go to Activity for getting network data. If same Activity have multiple child who need data from network then Activity will be answerable.

Comment: Here is the thing guys: I did not mean that its a good idea to populate a fragment itself with any "smart" logic. Imagine a scenario: I develop a fragment and my body is responsible for the code of a parent activity - who will need to implement network related classes? Technically I might not even know during fragment development whether this functionality will be used again to factor it out to the activity. On the other hand activity becomes an uber class like single source of everything.